# Running tests on intellij throwing OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, out-of-memory, fedora

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:584)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190)


java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I am on the latest Fedora distro, running Intellij Ultimate. I have also configured Maven Runnger VM Options as `-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=4g`

How could I debug why the VM Options are not getting applied to the test or why the tests even dont run with default options. Same project works perfectly fine on another machine running Ubuntu Trusty.

Comment: Does this occur when running tests in IDEA directly or also when running `mvn test` from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/jschwart/openjdk-7/ fixed the issue. Binaries are here https://schwart6.home.xs4all.nl/fedora25/binaries/

Answer (score 1):

> How could I debug why the VM Options are not getting applied to the
>   test or why the tests even dont run with default options. Same project
>   works perfectly fine on another machine running Ubuntu Trusty.

You can apply a process of elimination to find out which argument is causing trouble.  I suspect in this case it's either the `MaxPermSize` flag being equal to `Xmx`, or the `Xmx` value being set to `4gb` (if the system in question is a 32-bit architecture).

Try modifying the flags (of course make a backup!) to test those hypothesis and iterate from there.